# Update element value in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm updating an xml file by this code,

```
public static void UpdateDesignCfg(string ChildName, string[,] AttribWithValue)
{        
    try
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("DesignCfg.xml");
        XmlElement formData = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("//" + ChildName);
        if (formData != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < AttribWithValue.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                formData.SetAttribute(AttribWithValue[i, 0], AttribWithValue[i, 1]);                    
            }
        }
        doc.Save("DesignCfg.xml");                                 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

but I've often get this error ( not every time)

```
the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

so, Is there any way to " Release " the file after every change ?

Comment: Do you get this error in your given catch block or do you get it when trying to access it from outside?

Might it be possible that you access it somewhere while trying to edit it here?

Comment: Do you have write access rights?

Comment: @private_meta I get it in Catch Block, and I've access to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The file is accessed from another place and is not closed. Use the same `Load` method in the other place.

Comment: thanks for help, I'll try the second one because the first one didn't help me :)

Comment: It didn't help me :( could you give me the code please ?

Comment: @aEkBKF Are you sure no other code/app accesses the same file (is UpdateDesignCfg method called from multiple places or parallel threads)? And do you get exception when you `Load` or when you `Save`?

Comment: In fact, I open the file on MainForm.Load() to get the current cfg (get elements value), and when I try to update an element at runtime, I often get that error.

Comment: Yes, the method called from multiple places

Comment: @aEkBKF How do you open the file in MainForm.Load()?

Comment: like this :

    public static Color GetColor(string ChildName, string Attribute)
    {
    Color clr = new Color(); string v = "";
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("DesignCfg.xml");
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader);
    foreach (XmlNode chldNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
      if (chldNode.Name == ChildName)
     {
         v = chldNode.Attributes["" + Attribute + ""].Value;
     }
    }
    clr = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(v);
    return clr;
    }

Comment: @aEkBKF What if you don't create XmlTextReader, but rather use `Load` as you do in your sample code?

Comment: _"The problem is that Load(filename) doesn't close the stream"_ - can you back that up? It would be crazy if it was true.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I admit this is wrong. Just didn't delete the answer since we do discussion.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved my problem, it was my bad readXml method ^^

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, thanks so much @Ulugbek Umirov for help, the problem was on my ReadXmlFile Method, it was like this :

```
public static Color GetColor(string ChildName, string Attribute) 
{
 Color clr = new Color(); string v = ""; 
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("DesignCfg.xml"); 
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
 XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader); 
foreach (XmlNode chldNode in node.ChildNodes) 
{ 
   if (chldNode.Name == ChildName) 
      v = chldNode.Attributes["" + Attribute + ""].Value; 
} 
clr = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(v);
return clr; 
}
```

and the new one is :

```
public static Color GetColor(string ChildName, string Attribute)
{
  Color clr = new Color();
  string v = "";
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load("DesignCfg.xml");
  XmlElement formData = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("//" + ChildName);
  if (formData != null)
     v = formData.GetAttribute(Attribute);    
  clr = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(v);
  return clr;
}
```

Thanks all for help :)